# Monitoring ports in Linux

Tags: ubuntu, process, port

How to find out what processes are listening on specific ports in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lsof -i :<port #>
```

Comment: This will show only processes owned by user. So, unless you're logged in as root, prepend sudo.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you are root.

```
netstat -lnp
```

The 4th and 7th fields are what you want.

Alternatively you can get much more detailed information with [lsof(1)](http://freshmeat.net/projects/lsof/).

Answer (score 2):

best way i know of is:

```
netstat -lpn
```

run as super user

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well for me on linux only:
`netstat -anp|egrep -i 'PID/Program|LISTEN'`

-a = All sockets
-n = doNt resolve IPs
-p = show Pids/Programs associated with each

Answer (score 0):

su -c netstat -lpna